# Nativescript modal dialog css selector

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm using Nativescript Angular for my project.

I have added the class to differentiate tablet/phone on my root view in `app.component` which is `.page-tablet` for tablets and `.page-phone` for phones, so that I can specify styles for tablets/phones by using different selectors.

This works fine generally, but when it comes to modal view, the selector doesn't work.
For example I have a class `.modal-container` in my modal, and I set in the `app.css` file :

```
 .page-phone .modal-container { font-size: 15; }
 .page-tablet .modal-container { font-size: 30; }
```

Neither my phone nor the tablet would take the `font-size` here.

This issue only happens in **Modal dialog** though, other components work as expected.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

These are my app.component codes

app.component.tns.html

```
 <page-router-outlet #RootElem></page-router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('RootElem', { static: false }) rootElem: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (device.deviceType === 'Tablet') {
        this.rootElem.nativeElement.className = 'page-tablet';
    } else if (device.deviceType === 'Phone') {
        this.rootElem.nativeElement.className = 'page-phone';
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your root element, where exactly you are applying `page-[phone|tablet]` class? Can you show your code on app component?

Comment: @Manoj I added my app component.